Opentelemetry in java
How can i enable opentelemetry in java app. Looking for auto instrumentation. Below is my Dockerfile.
Detailed step view would be appreciated.
Dockerfile
FROM openjdk:17
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-alpine
work dir
WORKDIR /xyz-service
copy .mvn/wrapper to work dir
COPY ./.mvn /xyz-service
copy src to work dir
COPY ./src /xyz-service/src
Copy the executable JAR file into the container at /app
ADD ./target/xyz-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar xyz-service.jar
EXPOSE 8080
Command to run the application
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "xyz-service.jar"]
